# Oauth 2.0 for android app with a backend web server

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am building an android app that accesses youtube data api. For that i need to implement oauth 2.0 authentication mechanism. I am also implementing a backend web server as a middleware for my app so that   the response that i get from youtube server is received by my server first, which processes the response and then sends it to my client app.
Please help me out in figuring the authentication flow that i need to implement and the way I should go about my Oauth 2.0 implementation for my use-case.
Thank You in advance. Any help will be appreciated.